# Qt 5.8.0 firebird QSqlQuery error

Tags: c++, sql, qt, firebird

After connecting to the firebird embedded does not execute the SQL request. 
In the database there is one table called a test.

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QIBASE");
db.setDatabaseName("C:\data.fdb");
db.setUserName("SYSDBA");
db.setPassword("masterkey");

if (db.open()) {
   qDebug() << "success";
}
else {
   qDebug() << db.lastError();
}

QSqlQuery q("", db);
q.exec("show tables;");

qDebug() << q.lastError();
qDebug() << q.lastError().type();
qDebug() << q.lastQuery();
```

debug:

```
success
QSqlError("-104", "Could not prepare statement", "Dynamic SQL Error - SQL                         
error code = -104 - Token unknown - line 1, column 1 - show")
2
"show tables;"
```

Comment: `db.setDatabaseName("C:\DATA.FDB");` <-- Surely that line is resulting in a compile time warning, is it not? `\D` is not a valid escape character in C++.

Comment: I had data.fdb - without errors

Answer (score 2):

The `show` command is not a part of the SQL so the `show tables;` is not a command that Firebird engine recognises. The various `show` commands are implemented by some external tools, ie [isql](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/isql-show.html).

Try ie `select 1 from rdb$database` instead as a "test statement" (the `rdb$database` is a Firebird's version of the Oracle's `dual` table). Or try to select from the `test` table you know is in the database.

Comment: When I enter the same query in cmd, everything is fine. QSqlQuery::exec() and command cmd is not the same thing?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "When I enter the same query in cmd, everything is fine"? cmd like in terminal's command line?

Comment: I used Firebird ISQL Tool

Comment: @listins That works in ISQL because [`show tables` is an ISQL command](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/isql-show.html#d0e37786), not a Firebird query. You'll need to use something like `select RDB$RELATION_NAME from RDB$RELATIONS` (optionally with `where RDB$RELATION_TYPE = 0` to only list tables, and not views, virtual or external tables)

Comment: Where can I find out a list of all possible queries? Or do I need to communicate through ISQL?

Comment: @listins See the [Firebird 2.5 Language Reference](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25.html)